# Matching moments in Gaussian Mixtures

Tags: moments, method-of-moments

Consider $$q^{\backslash n}(\theta) = \mathcal{N}(\theta | m^{\backslash n},v^{\backslash n}I)$$ and $$f_n(\theta) = (1-w)\mathcal{N}(x_n | \theta,I) + w\mathcal{N}(x_n|0,aI)$$ Then let $$\hat{P}(\theta) = q^{\backslash n}(\theta)f_n(\theta) = (1-w)\mathcal{N}(x_n | m^{\backslash n},(v^{\backslash n}+1)I)\mathcal{N}(\theta | \mu, \Sigma) + w\mathcal{N}(x_n|0,aI)\mathcal{N}(\theta | m^{\backslash n},v^{\backslash n}I)$$ where $$\mu = \frac{1}{v^{\backslash n}+1}m^{\backslash n} + \frac{v^{\backslash n}}{v^{\backslash n}+1}x_n$$ and $$\Sigma = \frac{v^{\backslash n}}{v^{\backslash n}+1}I$$

This problem is in the Exercise 10.39 of Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning (by Chris Bishop). Let $P(\theta) = \frac{1}{Z_n}\hat{P}(\theta)$ where $Z_n$ is the partition function. I wonder how we obtained the mean of $\theta$ (equation 10.244 in the book), which is $$\mathrm{E}_{p(\theta)}[\theta] = m^{\backslash n} + v^{\backslash n}\nabla_{m^{\backslash n}}\ln Z_n.$$

Comment: Because the notation "$^{\backslash n}$" is not standard, please include an explanation of what it means.

Comment: "\n" was referring to "without data point x_n" in the book. But it is just a notation and can be ignored.

Comment: It's not clear precisely how one should ignore it.  Should we erase all subscripts and superscripts involving $n$'s or just the slash superscripts, for instance?  It would be much better for you to simplify your question so that it clearly asks what you need to ask.

Comment: I was just following the exact notation in the book, and I apologize for the confusion. We can erase all superscript '\n' in the question, and it'd be the same. I can re-post the question without all superscripts, but if someone is following Bishop's book, then they might be confused.

Comment: Also, the subscript 'n' is also NOT important. Namely, the function f_n can be written just 'f', the variable x_n as 'x', and the partition function Z_n as 'Z'.

Comment: In the first equation, what does that equal sign mean? What does "$\theta|m"$ mean?

Comment: The first equation means $q^{\backslash n}(\theta)$ is a normal distribution of $\theta$ with mean $m^{\backslash n}$ and variance $v^{\backslash n}I$. I missed the "I" in the variance. Sorry!

Comment: Can you please come back and do all those edits?

Answer (score 0):

The question is very unclear.
There is some $n$ is the question, you say it is not important, but after some calculus I think we have to take some limit $n \rightarrow +\infty$ to have the result.

Here is my answer. I consider the distribution in $\mathbb{R}$ (mean, variance, etc.)

**The term on the right** is easy to compute.
We have (using your notations):
$$Z = \int \hat{P}(\theta)d\theta = (1-w) \mathcal{N}(x|m, v+1) + w \mathcal{N}(x|0,a).$$

We take the $\log$ and isolate the terms in $m$, by writing the density $\mathcal{N}(x|m, v+1)$ explicitly we get:
$$\nabla_m \log Z = \nabla_m \log \mathcal{N}(x|m, v+1) = \nabla_m \left[ - \frac{(x-m)^2}{2(v+1)} \right] = \frac{x-m}{v+1}.$$
Then we obtain that the term on the right is:
$$m+\frac{v}{v+1}(x-m) = \frac{m+vx}{v+1}.$$

**The term on the left** can be computed as follows:
$$\frac{1}{Z}\int \theta \hat{P}(\theta)d\theta = \frac{\mu (1-w) \mathcal{N}(x|m,v+1)+ mw\mathcal{N}(x|0,a)}{(1-w) \mathcal{N}(x|m,v+1)+ w\mathcal{N}(x|0,a)}$$

Using some linear and bilinear properties of the Normal distribution, we have:
$$\frac{1}{Z}\int \theta \hat{P}(\theta)d\theta = \frac{\mu (1-w) (v+1)[\mathcal{N}(x|0,1)+m]+ mw[a\mathcal{N}(x|0,1)]}{(1-w)(v+1) [\mathcal{N}(x|0,1)+m]+ w[a\mathcal{N}(x|0,1)]}$$
So that:
$$\frac{1}{Z}\int \theta \hat{P}(\theta)d\theta = \frac{(1-w)(m+vx)\mathcal{N}(x|0,1)+ (1-w)(m+vx)m + wam\mathcal{N}(x|0,1)}{(1-w)(v+1) \mathcal{N}(x|0,1)+(1-w)(v+1)m + wa\mathcal{N}(x|0,1)}$$

Here there is a need for a property to use, that is not stated in your question (maybe in the limit $x_n \rightarrow \infty$), to obtain:
$$\frac{1}{Z}\int \theta \hat{P}(\theta)d\theta = \frac{ (1-w)(m+vx)m}{(1-w)(v+1)m}.$$
Finally:
$$\frac{1}{Z}\int \theta \hat{P}(\theta)d\theta = \frac{ m+vx}{v+1}.$$

**On the whole**, we obtain the expected result.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the derivation of the expectation. The reason I posted this question was I thought $\nabla_{m^{\backslash n}}\ln Z_n$ was a general technique in moment matching. The book briefly covers this topic on page 505 in equation 10.186 and 10.187. But now it seems I was wrong, and it is just a algebra trick.